# Spring + JSP - How to set value from database as default input text value?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jsp

I'm writing an application and I got some problems with displaying last ID from my database (incremented +1), I want in order to input field in JSP has a default value which will be last ID from database. I tried with some options like `value="id" or value "${patient.id}"`but it never worked. How should I do it properly? Here is a code:

RegistrationPatient.jsp:

```
<p style="font-size: 26">
        ID<input style="font-family: Century Gothic; font-size: 26"
            type="text" value="id" name="id" disabled="disabled" />
```

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/registration.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView registrationPatient(@ModelAttribute("patient") Patient patient){

    setAppContext();

    clinicService.getNextId(patient);

    ModelAndView reg = new ModelAndView("RegistrationPatient");
    return reg;

}
```

ClinicService:

```
     public void getNextId(Patient patient){
     ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("clinicconfig.xml");
     patientDAO = ctx.getBean("patientDAO", PatientDAOImpl.class);

     patient.setId(patient.getId());

    patientDAO.getNextId(patient);
    }
```

PatientDAOImpl:

```
public void getNextId(Patient patient) {
    String query = "SELECT idpatient FROM virtualclinic.patient ORDER BY idpatient DESC LIMIT 1";
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{
        con = dataSource.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()){
            int PID;
            PID = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1));
            int nextPID = PID + 1;
            patient.setId(String.valueOf(nextPID));
        }
       patient.getId();

    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Couldn't use just allow the db to provide an auto-incremented id?

Comment: It is auto-incremented, but I need ID incremented +1 from last ID, because when I'll add the patient then in ID field should be ID the next patient, which I am about to add.

Comment: Your code is wrong on multiple levels. First generating an id like that is a bad idea, what if 5 people at the same time enter a patient, they all get the same id, now which one would be the right one? Second you are creating a application context to obtain beans NEVER do that (unless you want memory issues, performance issues, weird transactional issues). You should be using a sequence or auto generated ID field for the patient id, don't rely on doing it yourself in java code like this.

Answer (score 0):

when you persist a record using jdbc, you can do this:

```
//assuming connection is setup
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(QUERY,
    new String[] { "patient_id" }); 
Long patientID= null;
if (ps.executeUpdate() > 0) {  
ResultSet generatedKeys = ps.getGeneratedKeys();    
if (null != generatedKeys && generatedKeys.next()) {        
    patientID = generatedKeys.getLong(1);
}
```

note the 2nd argument passed to prepareStatement() method pass name of primary key column, in this case patient_id is generated from sequence

Now that patientID has the id of the last patient record insert. You can incerement it by 1 and then show it in the jsp. 
I hope this is useful.